# Unable to log Kubernetes pod. no route to host

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubectl

Hi I am trying to get a kubernetes cluster to run an application I have in docker.

I have two ubuntu droplets on digital ocean I am using to do this.

I have the cluster created and I can create the deployment, however the pod keeps restarting and it doesn't give me a hit why. Am trying to find out why this is restarting so i can try to resolve the issue.

To find this out, I am aware you should be able to log a pod, however, when i try to run the log command on it, i get an error:

```
Error from server: Get https://10.16.0.8:10250/containerLogs/dev/dev-hangfire-deployment-9476b6c9-8wwcs/hangfire: dial tcp 10.16.0.8:10250: connect: no route to host
```

the command i am running is:
kubectl logs dev-hangfire-deployment-9476b6c9-8wwcs

I don't know why this is failing

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am trying to learn kubernetes and work with it, but its really hard to find resolutions to these issues.

Comment: Try to [troubleshoot cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/)

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin I took a look at the link. But a lot of it is over my head tbh and might be more granular than I need.
I ran the get nodes, and they are fine (which I know)
Would you have any recommendations of where to start or how toy break this down?
I am new to this really... 
I followed tutorials to set this up so i would have though (hoped) it isn't rare/granular issue

Comment: I would recommend to look into kubelet and kube-proxy logs(see details in troubleshoot document where to find them). If you can share this logs, that would be helpful

Comment: Also, probably would be helpful to check if firewalls are off on worker nodes

Comment: Take a look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#non-public-ip-used-for-containers)

Comment: @HelloWorld That is very interesting and looks like what I should be looking at, especially as it says about DigitalOcean.
Still a little confused how to use it though. (sorry I'm a noob) 
If i run the curl command I get the INTERNAL-IP.
if i run "ip addr show" there is an eth0 but no eth1
should be setting this node ip to the eth0 value?
also it doesn't give me any indication oin how to use --node-ip, but having look is it in the /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.... file?
Does this have to be dont for all slaves?

Comment: Run `kubectl get nodes -owide` and see if INTERNAL-IP and EXTERNAL-IP are correct. Regarding `--node-ip` flag, you are correct, it needs to be set on every node.